# How do I display only "Specific" project(s) on a separate View Page in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my **index.html.erb** page I have a list of all my projects `@projects = Project.order()`and have written code to determine if the project(s) are "dueSoon" or "Late" and added Styles. Now I have created a 2nd View Page called "Delinquent" where I want to display only the project(s) that are either late or duesoon. I am trying to figure out the best/cleanest way to display this. Here is my code from my index View:

```
<table class....
...
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
<% colorClass = project.late? ? "late" : project.dueSoon? ? "dueSoon" : "ok" %>
 <tr>
   <td class=<%= colorClass %>><%= link_to project.product, project %></td>
 ....
 ...
```

Now I know I want my logic to be something like IF (project) = late OR duesoon then true (Display project(s). I am just not 100% sure the best way to code this.

Thank You.

I looked at the Active Record Querying link you attached. I was looking at the Scope section 14.2 Merging of Scopes. Looks like I could do something like this:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 scope :late, -> { where(late: true) }
 scope :duesoon, -> { where(duesoon: true) }
 end
```

Then I it looks like I can merge them by doing `Projects.late.duesoon`

Please let me know if this logic looks somewhat accurate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to add a `delinquent` class method to Project.

Something like this in your model:

```
class Project               
  def self.delinquent
    where(delinquent: true)
  end
end
```

Then something like this in your view:

```
<% @projects.delinquent.each do |project| %>
```

Comment: Okay, I will look more into the displayable class. I'm new to ROR so still trying to learn all these new techniques as I go. I was trying to come up with an If/Else statement in the View itself based on the def late and def duesoon. But realize this isn't the cleanest method.

Comment: Your intuition is correct. You should investigate the Tell, Don't Ask principle. [0](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/tell-dont-ask) [1](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to define a scope in your project model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :displayable, where(:displayable => true)
  ...
end
```

From the Rails Guides: "Scoping allows you to specify commonly-used queries which can be referenced as method calls on the association objects or models. With these scopes, you can use every method previously covered such as where, joins and includes. All scope methods will return an ActiveRecord::Relation object which will allow for further methods (such as other scopes) to be called on it."

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

In your model / controller code, you can then use

```
 Project.displayable
```

to fire the query.

Comment: I looked at the Active Record Querying link you attached. I was looking at the Scope section 14.2 Merging of Scopes. Looks like I could do something like    'scope :displayLate ->'